# Execute menu driven commands on remote server using Maven

Tags: unix, maven, ssh

I did a bit of research on using Maven to execute commands on a remote server using some ssh exec plugin.

The thing that gets me though is I need to run a command which launches some menu driven program to stop a server and then start it up again.

I would basically have to perform the following tasks in sequence:

1. Connect to the remote server using SSH
2. Login with username/pass
3. Change directory to a particular location
4. Run a command at that location to launch a command line menu driven program (i.e. "`./control`")
5. Enter two commands to that menu driven program
6. Disconnect

The two commands are just numbers which represent choices from a menu it prints on the console, like:

```
Enter the number of the server you wish to stop:
[1] server1
[2] server2
[3] server3
```

I would enter "2" for example. Is this possible?

Comment: So how far have you got with this? Are you just stuck on step 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be to write a Perl script on the remote server that accepts the server number as an argument.

You could then use Perl's [Expect.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod) library to supply this argument to your `control` program when it prompts for input.

This then simplifies your Maven task to executing a script on a remote server, which presumably you are now happy with thanks to your research.

<sub>(If you've not used it before, Perl's Expect library is designed for exactly this use case - automatically supplying input to interactive command line programs.)</sub>